# Android - could not install *smartsocket* listener

Tags: android, sockets, android-studio, adb

When I try run my Android application I get this exception:

> Error while waiting for device: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to
>   create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: error: could not
>   install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: An
>   attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions. (10013) could not read ok from ADB Server
>   * failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemon 'C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server'
>   failed -- run manually if necessary

So I try do it manualy with these commands:

> adb kill-server

- response: * server not running *

> adb start-server

- response was next exception:

> *daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *   error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: An
>   attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access
>   permissions. (10013) could not read ok from ADB Server
>
> *failed to start daemon * error: cannot connect to daemon

I looking for adb process in my task manager but not running. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you have the situation where this keeps happening and killing and restarting still doesn't work it may be a problem with your adb installation. I had to reinstall adb to resolve this problem:

1. Reboot to ensure no instances of adb is running
2. Launch SDK Manager in Android Studio: Tools->Android->SDK Manager
3. Select the SDK Tools tab
4. Deselect Android SDK Platform-Tools item
5. Hit Apply
6. Check the on screen logs to make sure the un-installation succeeded and that the SDK/platform-tools folder is empty.

This should completely remove adb from your SDK.

1. Now re-select the Android SDK Platform-Tools item
2. Hit apply
3. Check the on screen logs that installation was successful.

I suspect in my case an update of the platform tools had failed perhaps because it failed to kill a running adb.exe and only a partial update was applied resulting in an unstable adb installation.

Answer (score 21):

Open command prompt and enter following command

```bash
netstat -ano | findstr :5037
```

This will show the process ID (832)

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:5037         0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       832
```

Now run the command

```bash
tasklist | findstr processID
```

(e.g `tasklist | findstr 832`)

It will show process name like `bash.exe`

Go to task manager and end the task `bash.exe` and use following command to start `adb`

```bash
adb start-server
```

Voila

Comment: your answer made my day. I was struggling with this issue for 4 days now. Upvoted

Comment: `netstat: illegal option -- o` - Help!

Comment: And if you are on a Mac, run this command to find the PID: lsof -i:5037

Comment: If you are on a Mac, after finding the PID with `lsof -i:5037`, kill the process with `kill -9 <PID>`. After that, run `adb start-server`

Answer (score 5):

I fixed it by adding the ADB to path:

```sh
sudo ln -s ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /bin/adb
```

And then killing the ADB server `adb kill-server` and starting the server again `adb start-server`.

Observation: I tried to kill java, tried to find the port where it was running using HTOP and Kill, aside from restarting everything but it was a pain in the ass

Answer (score 2):

I solved this for myself by simply closing the shell I'd been running adb commands in and starting a new one, inspired by Vinayak Mestri's answer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the culprit is Visual Studio 2017.  I found out this with the help of Vinayak's answer. I just closed Visual Studio 2017, then ADB started working.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting adb server uns an **External** terminal (CMD) did the job for me:

```
Android-SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe kill-server
Android-SDK/platform-tools/adb.exe start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

you just let "command prompt" to run as administrator.
so, you can run the command "nox_adb.exe connect 127.0.0.1:62001"
pic as follow:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAmXz.png

Answer (score 0):

thanks mestri
List the process id using 5037 port

> netstat -ano | findstr :5037

TCP    127.0.0.1:39187        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     5400
  TCP    127.0.0.1:39188        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     5400
  TCP    127.0.0.1:39798        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     5400
  TCP    127.0.0.1:39902        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     7296
  TCP    127.0.0.1:40148        127.0.0.1:5037         ESTABLISHED     5400
here 5400,7296 is the pid number

> taskkill /pid pidnumber

THEN \n

> adb connect localhost:62001

adb server version (41) doesn't match this client (36); killing...
* daemon started successfully *
connected to localhost:62001