# how to start adb server?

Tags: android, android-studio, adb

hi im getting the error:

> Unable to create Debug Bridge: Unable to start adb server: error: could not install *smartsocket* listener: cannot bind to 127.0.0.1:5037: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions. (10013)
>   This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
>   Please contact the application's support team for more information.
>   could not read ok from ADB Server
>   * failed to start daemon *
>   error: cannot connect to daemon
>   'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary

How can I fix this issue? i have tried to uninstall the sdk platform tool and reinstall but that does not seem to work, any suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

use:

```
adb start-server
```

also (to shutdown the server):

```
adb kill-server
```

(adb must be in the PATH)

Comment: can you explain to me how i can do this?

Comment: sure, you need to run that command.. adb program is located in Android-folder/Sdk/platform-tools

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, found the solution here:
[stackoverflow - Android - could not install *smartsocket* listener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42339835/6908937)

In summary, for windows:
Open command prompt and enter following command

```
netstat -ano | findstr :5037
```

example output - final column is process id (PID)

```
TCP 127.0.0.1:5037 0.0.0.0:0 LISTENING 832
```

in this example, 832 is PID

Now run command

```
tasklist | findstr _PID_ (e.g tasklist | findstr 832)
```

It will show process/service name like `bash.exe`  (for me it was `MBAM.exe`)

go to task manager and end the task `bash.exe` and use following command to start `adb`

```
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Tools menu at the sop of your screen and then Navigate to 'Android'.

Click 'Enable ADB Integration'

To restart the service, uncheck and recheck that selection.

From the command line, navigate to the location of your adb.exe and enter `adb kill-server` then use the `adb start-server` command

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work

Comment: I updated my answer with command line usage