# Automate android using python

Tags: python, adb

I am trying to automate android mobile using python's pure-python-adb package but when I run the following code:

```
from ppadb.client import Client as AdbClient
# Default is "127.0.0.1" and 5037
client = AdbClient(host="127.0.0.1", port=5037)
print(client.version())
```

I get error in Pycharm as:
RuntimeError: ERROR: connecting to 127.0.0.1:5037 [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
Is adb running on your computer?

Please can anyone help me with it

Comment: Try referring this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40618200/android-could-not-install-smartsocket-listener to start the adb server before connecting it to the Python's Adb client.

Answer (score 0):

Switch on developer mode in your phone and connect it to your laptop using a physical data transfer (or changing) cable.
REMEMBER: Switch on 'USB debugging' on your phone.
Then go to cmd terminal and make sure you have adb requirements from android studio installed. Once that's there, go to terminal and type.

```
adb devices
```

if your phone shows up, you should be connected. You can then type

```
adb shell
```

or:
adb connect tcpip 5555
to connect over the internet